# C++ LibUSB write from one USB to another

Tags: c++, usb, sd-card, libusb

There are two devices connected to my computer via USB. One of the devices receives a series of commands and then sends data to the computer every thirty seconds.

The other device will be a SD card drive. The goal is to save the data as a file on the SD card without over-writing any previous files. How do I distinguish between the devices? What command(s) is (are) appropriate for writing to an SD card without over-writing previous data?

Comment: Use unique filenames based on date.

Comment: Why would you confuse a disk with a device that sends data?

Comment: I intend to use a timestamp as the filename. I'm just trying to figure out how to send it to the usb drive.

Comment: The usual way is in the `open()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving the data to the harddrive. Then I wrote a routine using crontab that zipped the days files then transferred the files to a usb. I had to find the physical location of the usb by first identifying with the fdisk command.

This software was used in unison with the hardware I built on the International Space Station. The unit successfully mapped the radiation environment in low-earth orbit. I am very happy with the results.